# SamsungWidget_ProgramMonitor is not listed on Widgets selection screen

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, app-widgets

On my Samsung Galaxy S3 (GT-I9300) with the latest stock ROM there are following files present in `/system/app`:

- SamsungWidget_ProgramMonitor.apk (484 kb -rw-r-r--)
- SamsungWidget_ProgramMonitor.odex (5829 kb -rw-r-r--)

but the widget is not listed in "Apps and widgets", so I can't add it to the home screen.

How to add it?

Below is a picture of the widget. This is not a screenshot of my phone.

[image]